# Order of magnitude of ions in water

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, water

My book says water has approximately $\pu{3.35E28 molecules/m^3}$  and that only a small part of water molecules are dissociated to $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ ions and that the approximate amount of ions of each sign is $\pu{6E19 ions/m^3}.$

I am trying to prove the last part. I thought I could used the ionic product of water

$$[\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}] = \pu{1E-14},$$

so that in neutral conditions

$$[\ce{H+}] = \pu{1E-7 ions/L} = \pu{1E-4 ions/m^3}.$$

What am I doing wrong or how should I proceed?

Comment: You may know the concentration does not have dimension ion/L, , but mol/L.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: 1 cubic meter of water contains $\pu{1E-4}$ moles of $\ce{H+}$ ions. But one mole is $\pu{6E23}$ atoms or ions.

So, $\pu{1E-4 mol}$ contains $\pu{1E-4}\times\pu{6E23} = \pu{6E19 ions}.$
Here we are.

Comment: Regarding typesetting, there are three ways of exponentiation I can think of: **1**: use MathJax, `$10^{23}$` → $10^{23}$; **2**: use MathJax and `\pu` macro from `mhchem`, `$\pu{E23}$` → $\pu{E23}$ or `$\pu{1E23}$` → $\pu{1E23}$; **3**: use HTML tags, `10<sup>23</sup>` → 10²³. Method **1** is preferred and the most versatile; method **2** is handy when **p**hysical **u**nits (hence `\pu` macro acronym) are involved, e.g. `$\pu{6.022E23 mol-1}$` → $\pu{6.022E23 mol-1}$. I corrected your post accordingly, so you can use it as an example.

Comment: For more details please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It is exactly what I need. You are an angel

Comment: No prob, I'm glad I could help. Sorry, however, I'm anything but an angel.